# Whty does dangerous permission already granted on marshmallow emulator?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to test new permission system for android 6.0 however emulator already grants permission when checked first time. Is there any specific settings to test new permission system on emulators?

Edit:

I am asking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
 targetSdkVersion is 23

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 23

Comment: 1) Which permissions does your app request? Not all permissions need to be granted by the user. 2) Did you do a clean install of the app or did you upgrade from an older version that had a lower `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: Do a full uninstall and reinstall of the app, and see if your problem clears up.

Comment: @CommonsWare it worked after reinstall. Thank you all.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468